# Oracle Query hierarchical level cintaining when case with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case-when

I cannot solve a problem with my GROUP BY problem in my query containing CASE...WHEN

Could you help me please with that?

```
select  ID,
        CODE, 
        NOM AS TITLE,
        level,
        ID_PARENT,
        CASE ID_PARENT
            WHEN 1111 THEN 'MAIN'
            ELSE 
            (
                SUBSTR(
                (
                SELECT CODE FROM units o
                INNER JOIN LIB_UNITS_MV oLab on oLab.ID = o.ID WHERE o.ID = units.ID_PARENT AND LNG_CD = 'ENG'
                )        
                , 7)      
            )
        END AS "PARENT_CODE"         
from units
INNER JOIN LIB_UNITS_MV orgLab on orgLab.ID = units.ID
WHERE orgLab.LNG ='ENG' 
start with units.id = 1111
connect by prior u.ID = u.ID_PARENT
GROUP BY ID, CODE, NOM, level, ID_PARENT
```

I obtain the error "not a GROUP BY expression" because I have the WHEN...CASE

Thank you in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: you may use aggregation such as `max(case when .... end) as "PARENT_CODE"`, and remove `ID_PARENT` from `GROUP BY - list`. Btw, remove `ID_PARENT` between `CASE` and `WHEN`.

Comment: Hi, I need the ID_PARENT (I update my post), How I can do ?

Comment: @coeurdange57, Why do you need a group by when there is no aggregate function?

Comment: Because I obtain several records with the same results

Comment: Hi, I have done an error and now it's working with the max.

Comment: If I add a new field in order to have the LABEL_PARENT and follow the same way, I have now another issue: 'Missing expression'         `max(
            SELECT o.CODE FROM units o
            INNER JOIN LIB_UNITS_MV oLab on oLab.ID = o.ID WHERE o.ID = units.ID_PARENT AND LNG_CD = 'ENG'
        ) AS "LABEL_PARENT"`

Comment: I considered the case, if you do not use ID_PARENT as a non-aggregated column in the SELECT-list, for your current case of course you need in the GROUP BY list. By the way your problem should raise due to using alias `u`, I suppose you intended to use an alias `u` for users, and forget to alias that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase when you `group by` you need to group by sufficient number of columns, which you use in `select` statement, outside aggregating functions (`min`, `max`, `sum` etc). So in your case this means - you can either group by all columns used in your `case` statement, or group by the whole `case` statement (just copy it over to your `group by`), or any set of sub-combinations of the whole `case`, altogether covering it completely. However - since you are not using any aggregate functions I would just do `distinct` and drop `group by` altogether.

Comment: I add the distinct bu the problem is still the same

Comment: buy you also removed ```group by``` (any everything after) ?

Comment: When I removed the group by clause I obtain double results

Comment: Ok, but at least one of the columns isn't doubled, right ?